# Can I debug Desktop Safari with Chrome Devtools?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, safari-web-inspector

Safari's Web Inspector is absolutely awful, and it keeps crashing on me. One of my colleagues suggested using Chrome Devtools to inspect Safari pages via Remote Debugging. I haven't found anything on Google for how to do such a thing--is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari and Chrome use different debugging protocols (initially these were very similar, but over time they grew into separate things). Thankfully, there is a Google project that does the translation between these protocols - [iOS WebKit Debug Proxy](https://github.com/google/ios-webkit-debug-proxy). It doesn't mention desktop Safari though.

Comment: Thanks. I was afraid this was the case--I wasn't sure if their respective codebases had diverged too much yet.